# How can I add run-help to zshrc without errors?

Tags: zsh, iterm

`zshcontrib` suggests adding the following to `.zshrc` to use the `run-help` command:

```
unalias run-help
autoload run-help
```

However when I add it I get the error
`.zshrc:unalias:9: no such hash table element: run-help`

If I run the commands manually though there's no issue.

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'd say, this is just a warning, because `run-help` isn't aliased at that time. It works from the command line, because there it is defined because of `autorun run-help` in your `.zshrc`.

Comment: If you want to get rid of this warning message, the usual trick is to redirect stderr for this command like so: `unalias run-help 2> /dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Debian? If so, then `/etc/zshrc` [already does it for you](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/zsh/-/blob/debian/debian/zshrc#L103), which would explain the error: `run-help` has already been unaliased by the time Zsh executes the commands in your `.zshrc` file.